# How can you get a sprite to follow another sprite in Java?

Tags: sprite, 2d-games, sprite-sheet

Here is the code for the initial character:

```
public class Player extends Mob {

    private InputHandler input;
    private int colour = Colours.get(-1, 111, 145, 543);
    private int scale = 1;
    protected boolean isSwimming = false;
    private int tickCount = 0;

    public Player(Level level, int x, int y, InputHandler input) {
        super(level, "Player", x, y, 1);
        this.input = input;
    }

    public void tick() {

        int xa = 0;
        int ya = 0;

        if (input.up.isPressed()) {
            ya--;
        }

        if (input.down.isPressed()) {
            ya++;
        }

        if (input.left.isPressed()) {
            xa--;
        }

        if (input.right.isPressed()) {
            xa++;
        }

        if (xa != 0 || ya != 0) {
            move(xa, ya);
            isMoving = true;
        } else {
            isMoving = false;
        }
        if (level.getTile(this.x >> 3, this.y >> 3).getId() == 3) {
            isSwimming = true;
        }
        if (isSwimming && level.getTile(this.x >> 3, this.y >> 3).getId() != 3) {
            isSwimming = false;
        }
        tickCount++;
        this.scale = 1;


    }

    public void render(Screen screen) {



        int xTile = 0;
        int yTile = 28;

        int walkingSpeed = 4;
        int flipTop = (numSteps >> walkingSpeed) & 1;
        int flipBottom = (numSteps >> walkingSpeed) & 1;

        if (movingDir == 1) {
            xTile += 2;
        } else if (movingDir > 1) {
            xTile += 4 + ((numSteps >> walkingSpeed) & 1) * 2;
            flipTop = (movingDir - 1) % 2;
        }

        int modifier = 8 * scale;
        int xOffset = x - modifier / 2;
        int yOffset = y - modifier / 2 - 4;
        if (isSwimming) {
            int waterColour = 0;
            yOffset += 4;
            if (tickCount % 60 < 15) {
                waterColour = Colours.get(-1, -1, 225, -1);
            } else if (15 <= tickCount % 60 && tickCount % 60 < 30) {
                yOffset -= 1;
                waterColour = Colours.get(-1, 225, 115, -1);
            } else if (30 <= tickCount % 60 && tickCount % 60 < 45) {
                waterColour = Colours.get(-1, 115, -1, 225);
            } else {
                waterColour = Colours.get(-1, 225, 115, -1);
            }
            screen.render(xOffset, yOffset + 3, 0 + 27 * 32, waterColour, 0x00, 1);
            screen.render(xOffset + 8, yOffset + 3, 0 + 27 * 32, waterColour, 0x01, 1);
        }

        // upper body
        screen.render(xOffset + (modifier * flipTop), yOffset, xTile + yTile * 32, colour, flipTop, scale);
        screen.render(xOffset + modifier - (modifier * flipTop), yOffset, (xTile + 1) + yTile * 32, colour, flipTop,
                scale);

        if (!isSwimming) {
            // lower body
            screen.render(xOffset + (modifier * flipBottom), yOffset + modifier, xTile + (yTile + 1) * 32, colour,
                    flipBottom, scale);
            screen.render(xOffset + modifier - (modifier * flipBottom), yOffset + modifier,
                    (xTile + 1) + (yTile + 1) * 32, colour, flipBottom, scale);
        }


    }

    public boolean hasCollided(int xa, int ya) {

        int xMin = 0;
        int xMax = 7;
        int yMin = 1;
        int yMax = 7;

        for (int x = xMin; x < xMax; x++) {
            if (isSolidTile(xa, ya, x, yMin)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        for (int x = xMin; x < xMax; x++) {
            if (isSolidTile(xa, ya, x, yMax)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        for (int y = yMin; y < yMax; y++) {
            if (isSolidTile(xa, ya, xMin, y)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        for (int y = yMin; y < yMax; y++) {
            if (isSolidTile(xa, ya, xMax, y)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

can get another character to load at a given location; however, I cannot figure out an algorithm to have it follow the initial player. In other words the second one will follow these same collision and commands. Any help understanding is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Depending on how you implement your game map. If by grid, you can let the character which is following you to move into your previously occupied grid.

Comment: I am using 16 x 16 sprites on a grid based map (500 x 500). After removing what you recommended, the sprite still acted in the same manor as my question provided. I am not sure I quite have the skill yet to know how to implement getting the sprite to follow the previously occupied grid.

Comment: You can have a variable to store your previous grid location. Then you can have a condition to trigger the NPC to follow you. (e.g. when you move into a new grid, trigger the NPC to move into your previous grid) Basically just like the Snake game where the other segments of the body will follow the head.

Comment: I would like to thank you for taking the time to comment. Can you provide an example of what the syntax my resemble?